# pgfpages and section

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I'm making a Beamer presentation. I need to show some notes on a second screen, so I'm using pgfpages.

Whereas, when I put a section, it appears 2 times :/ Here, it's a minimal code with the problem. Have you any idea ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{test}
toto
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Never use `\section` inside a frame, it should always be outside.

Unrelated to the problem: the option `francais` for Babel is *deprecated*, use `french` instead

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
toto
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```